# Jquery selecting only all but one with similar id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's presume I have 5 divs with id's of #job1, #job2, #job3, #job4, #job5.   I want to use jquery to hide all of them but say the one with div id of #Job2.  Is there any selector syntax that would allow me to apply to all those id's except #job2?

Comment: A better approach might be to put the same class on all the elements, and use that as a selector instead (then use `.not(#job2)` to remove the one you want to ignore.)

Comment: @showdev Please post your suggestion - it is the correct answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure can! There are a few ways to accomplish this; below is an example leveraging a combination of jQuery's [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), [Attribute Ends With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), and the [`:not()` Selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```js
$("[id^='job']:not([id$='2']").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="job1">job1</div>
<div id="job2">job2</div>
<div id="job3">job3</div>
<div id="job4">job4</div>
<div id="job5">job5</div>
```

As was discussed in the comments to your question, this is likely not the most ideal way to accomplish this task - classes might be a more robust way of targeting each of these elements.

Comment: Yes, I agree not the usual most practical way but this particular case, this is exactly what I was looking for.  I get a little rusty with jQuery after not using it for years.  Thank you!  I appreciate your quick and very helpful response.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a complex selector, you might be better off putting a shared classname on all the elements and using that as the selector:

```js
$('.jobs').not('#job2').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="job1" class="jobs">Job</div>
<div id="job2" class="jobs">Job</div>
<div id="job3" class="jobs">Job</div>
<div id="job4" class="jobs">Job</div>
<div id="job5" class="jobs">Job</div>
```

Comment: This also has the advantage over the attribute selector approach, of not performing a DOM scan, as an attribute can be on pretty much any element.  But class lookups are optimized.